# Combine multiple powerpoint 2007 slide shows

Tags: windows, windows-vista, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

I have several power point sideshows which I want to play in order and on a loop, I use Power point 2007, and can't find the 'insert slide from file' option that used to be in 2003.

If push comes to shove, I will have to use each slide as a static image and use photo gallery or something to view them, however I'd really like to have the animations working normally.

most of the slides use a master slide, so simply copying all the slides into a master file doesn't work as they will lose their background layouts etc.

Windows Vista, Power point 2007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit: just found a youtube video on the subject:

[Combine PowerPoint 2007 Slides from Different Presentations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuvO6yjob_o)

Step by step:

1. Open Powerpoint 2007, be sure focus on the 'Home' tab
2. Click on the arrow below 'New slide' and then select 'Reuse slide'
3. From the Reuse slides tab on the right - click 'Browse' and then 'Browse file' - select your Powerpoint file you want to insert slides from
4. Choose if you would like to keep the source formatting or not by using the tick box at the bottom of the reuse slides tab
5. Click the slides you want to use and they will be inserted automatically (or right click on a slide and then 'use all slides')

job done :-)

Comment: This is the correct process for merging PowerPoint 2010 slide decks as well.

Answer (score 1):

***Combine presentations***

1. Open the presentation you want to add slides to.

   *Tip  If you are merging two presentations with an unequal number of slides, open the presentation with the greatest number of slides.*
2. On the Slides tab in normal view (view: A way of displaying the contents of a presentation and providing the user with the means to interact with it.), click the slide  (thumbnail: A miniature representation of a picture.) thumbnail that you want the added slides to follow.
3. On the Insert menu, click Slides from Files.
4. Click Browse to look for the file; in the Browse dialog box, select the file, and then click Open.
5. To preserve the current formatting of the slides you want to copy, in the lower corner of the Slide Finder dialog box, select the Keep source formatting check box. (When this check box is cleared, the copied slides assume the formatting of the slide they're inserted after.)
6. Do one of the following:

   - To insert selected slides, click the slides you want to insert, and then click Insert.
   - To insert all the slides, click Insert All.

Before clicking Close in the dialog box, you can browse for other presentations and insert more slides.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/HA011587531033.aspx#CombineMult)

Viedo [Link](http://office.microsoft.com/assistance/asstvid.aspx?assetid=XT011862951033&vwidth=720&vheight=540&type=mediaplayer&CTT=11&Origin=HA011587531033) from Ms Office site

Comment: Thanks for that - but on the insert menu in 2007 there is no 'slides from files' so you have to choose 'reuse slides'

you can select all slides by right clicking and 'select all slides'

Comment: before that u have add slides using slide finder

Comment: can check the video link . that might be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

On the Home Ribbon > New Slide > [right at the bottom] > Re-use slides

This gives you a task pane to browse etc, very similar to old method.
**NB: Tick the box at the bottom to keep source formatting before importing**

But notice that doing this also created lots of slide masters, as it imports the same master over and over again.

The slide sorter copy> paste > keep source formatting only imports the masters once, but it will bring in associated masters that are not actually used, so depending on how many slides you have and how many masters, this might be more or fewer than the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I've always just use copy and paste (with Slide Sorter view).

To keep formatting, immediately after paste select "Keep Source Formatting" in the paste options drop down that appears next to the pasted slides.